# Trying to blur just the face (python)

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to blur just the face by using the following script, but end up blurring the entire image. Any suggestions on how to change the script such that it blurs only the faces?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

img = cv2.imread('beatles.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Detecting faces
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]


# To show the detected faces
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

k = np.array(([1/9, 1/9, 1/9], [1/9, 1/9, 1/9], [1/9, 1/9, 1/9]), np.float32)

# Blurring of just the faces in a picture 
skaldetlykkes = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, k)
cv2.imshow("Ladetskje", skaldetlykkes)
cv2.waitKey (5000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code sample will apply your box filter only on the faces:

```
import cv2

# Load the cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# Read the input image
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

# Convert into grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Detect faces
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)

# Blur the faces, i.e. only the ROIs defined by faces
k = np.array(([1/9, 1/9, 1/9], [1/9, 1/9, 1/9], [1/9, 1/9, 1/9]), np.float32)
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    img[y:y+h,x:x+w] = cv2.filter2D(img[y:y+h,x:x+w], -1, k)

# Display the output
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

this code sample

```
import cv2

# Load the cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# Read the input image
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

# Convert into grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Detect faces
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)

# Draw rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

# Display the output
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

from [Face Detection](https://towardsdatascience.com/face-detection-in-2-minutes-using-opencv-python-90f89d7c0f81) should compute the rectangle area you want to blur.

Then you just need to apply an average function on the area :) (Blur = window average)